# Working with Text Editor in Angular 8 / Spring Boot application

Tags: angular, postgresql, spring-boot

I am working on school management application that should offer, amongst others, the possibility for an admin to create an article (news article for example). This article can include images, links, italic or bold expressions...In general, all what a basic text editor can offer.

Technically, i don't know what are the technologies needed in the front and the back. Besides, i find a problem to figure out what is/are the model entities that are suitable.

Help me please, thanks.